# How To Get Enderman / Ghast Into Minecart

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

How can we get hard-to-catch mobs (like Enderman and Ghasts) into a Minecart?
Are there any special tricks to make it easier?

Comment: Flagging as unclear. I can't understand what your talking about.

Comment: @Alex I suggested an edit that makes this more clear. Kimatuy basically wants to know what the best way is to catch an enderman/ghast with a Minecart, since these mobs are hard-to-catch.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One of the most easy ways to make an Enderman get into a minecart is like so:

Fist you want to put on a pumpkin in place of a helmet.  This will make so the Enderman don't run away.  This or try your best to look at their feet.

After this surround the Enderman in rails then minecarts.
[image]
They may get in them themselves or they may need a little persuading.  By hitting them they will (Might) jump into the minecarts and therefor be caught.  I found that they get caught more often when they walk in theselves.

Comment: Oh, not wearing a pumpkin can guarantee they don't run *away* :-)

Comment: Lol, When I took the photo I actually had F1 on so even though I had the pumpkin mask, it didn't show.

Comment: That's a good way, but does wearing a pumpkin mask can evitate that Ghasts attack you? And because Ghasts fly, is there a way to "attract them"?

Comment: I know you used to be able to catch them with a fishing pole and pull them, but I haven't tried and that information might be outdated.

Comment: I think that the fishing rode will do the thing, I took a look on the Minecraft Wiki.

Answer (score 2):

It is actually pretty easy to capture endermen and ghosts. All it takes is a bit of work. Before we start, the images will be from minecraft pe but the method can be transferred to the computer version.

1: You need the mob. To make things run smoother, you should make the mobs spawn where you want. For ghasts, you want to make a "ghast shelf." Make sure it is four blocks high. Now wait for a ghast to spawn. 
[image: Four blocks high]

It is a bit messed up because of how spawn eggs work in pe but trust me.

2: Trap the ghast so it doesn't move. You need to use "transparent" blocks (fences, glass, walls) to trap the ghast so when you move it, it doesn't take damage, and so it doesn't blow your face up. 
[image: trapped ghast]

3: Just poke a hole along the bottom and place rails on the floor. Make sure that the blocks with the rails on top are directly under the ghast. 
[image: Minecart]
Push the Minecart into the ghast. I repeat, push it. Do not place the Minecart under the ghast, or any mob, it just generally makes things harder.

4: Add a strip of transparent blocks above the rails so it doesn't shoot at you. 
[image: Rails]
And there you go! It seems others have already posted about endermen but my advice is to just push the Minecart into it. 
Thanks!

Comment: That's still a little complicated, but I think that wearing a pumpkin head solve a lot of thing or I am wrong ?

Comment: @Kimatuy It's only enderman that don't attack when you have a pumpkin on your head sadly. That would make things a lot easier though if it were true.

Comment: How sad is this... But if Pumpkin head can't do the same thing to Ghast as to Enderman, can other heads as a Wither Skeleton head do it?

Comment: @Kimatuy I am 99.99% sure that other skulls will not make a ghast oblivious. Ghasts are hostile. Enderman are passive until provoked, pumpkins prevent them from being provoked. Ghasts will shoot if they see you. No matter what.

Comment: Okay, I understood. Just too bad...

Answer (score -3):

There's an easier way all you have to do is get a minecraft on a rail and spawn the ghast right beside the minecart works with any mob.

Comment: It seems the problem here is under the assumption that a Ghast or Enderman are natural and not spawned in by an Egg/Cheats.